# extracting a cv.glmnet object from Tune_results

Tags: r, tidyverse, glmnet, tidymodels

Hi I am using tidy models and trying to generate a plot with RMSE as a function of log lambda with number of features along the top as posted below, if you are using glmnet you simple call `plot` on your `cv.glmnet` object and it will plot, However if using tidy models it is more complex,

Is it possible to extract a `cv.glmnet` object from your `tune_results` object and then call `plot` on that?

Plot

[image]

Comment: If you tuned lamba and then call `autoplot()` on your tune results, you will get almost exactly that kind of plot. See [here for an example](https://juliasilge.com/blog/tate-collection/).

Comment: Hi Julia, Thank you for your response, I have got that plot already using `autoplot()` the problem is it doesn't show the number of features as the lambda changes which is what I am interested in. 

I can dig them out if i call `pull_workflow_fit()` on my final fitted model but I then loose the RMSE at each CV